# how check if printing content on new page

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, windows-forms-designer

I have a DataGridView containing data about different customers, and my objective is to print each row on a separate page. However, I'm facing a problem where the data from two consecutive rows prints on the same page, overlapping each other. For example, if I have four rows in my DataGridView, the content of rows 1 and 2 prints on the same page, and similarly for rows 3 and 4.

Below is the relevant code snippet where I handle the printing logic:

```
private int currentRow = 0;
private void printDocument2_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    string companyName = "چوہان ڈیری فارمز"; // Your company name

    DateTime startDate = dtm_start.Value;
    DateTime endDate = dtm_end.Value;

    // Set font and brush for drawing
    Font headingfont = new Font("Times New Roman", 18, FontStyle.Bold);
    Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", 13, FontStyle.Regular);
    Font linefont = new Font("Jameel Noori Nastaleeq", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
    Font infofont = new Font("Times New Roman", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
    Font nofont = new Font("Jameel Noori Nastaleeq", 9, FontStyle.Regular);

    Brush brush = Brushes.Black;

    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);

    // Calculate the width and height of the page
    float pageWidth = e.PageBounds.Width;
    float pageHeight = e.PageBounds.Height;

    // Measure the size of the text
    SizeF textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(companyName, headingfont);

    // Calculate X coordinate to center the text
    float x = (pageWidth - textSize.Width) / 2;

    int xAxis = 190;

    
    if(currentRow<dataGridView2.Rows.Count)
    {

        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView2.Rows[currentRow];

        e.Graphics.DrawString(companyName, headingfont, brush, x, 17); // Adjust the Y coordinate as needed
        e.Graphics.DrawString("--------------------------------------------", linefont, brush, 20, 30); // Adjust the Y coordinate as needed

        e.Graphics.DrawString(":اکاؤنٹ نمبر", font, brush, xAxis, 60);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(":نام", font, brush, xAxis, 90);

        e.Graphics.DrawString("--------------------------------------------", linefont, brush, 20, 100);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(":تاریخ", font, brush, 225, 125);

        e.Graphics.DrawString("--------------------------------------------", linefont, brush, 20, 140);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(":سابقہ بیلنس", font, brush, xAxis, 170);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(":ٹوٹل لیٹر", font, brush, xAxis, 200);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(":دودھ رقم", font, brush, xAxis, 230);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(":پرچی رقم", font, brush, xAxis, 260);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(":بیلنس", font, brush, xAxis, 290);

        //e.Graphics.DrawString(startDate.Date.ToString(), font, brush, 160, 130);

        if (row.Cells["Id"].Value != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(row.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString(), font, brush, 150, 60);
        if (row.Cells["Customer Name"].Value != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(row.Cells["Customer Name"].Value.ToString(), font, brush, 70, 90);
        if (row.Cells["Previous Balance"].Value != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(row.Cells["Previous Balance"].Value.ToString(), font, brush, 70, 170);

        // write status in urdu for previous balance
        if (row.Cells["pStatus"].Value != null)
        {
            string pStatus = row.Cells["pStatus"].Value.ToString();
            if (pStatus == "Credit")
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString("جمع", font, brush, 40, 170);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString("بنام", font, brush, 40, 170);
            }
        }

        if (row.Cells["Total Liters"].Value != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(row.Cells["Total Liters"].Value.ToString(), font, brush, 70, 200);
        if (row.Cells["Milk Amount"].Value != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(row.Cells["Milk Amount"].Value.ToString(), font, brush, 70, 230);
        if (row.Cells["Parchi Amount"].Value != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(row.Cells["Parchi Amount"].Value.ToString(), font, brush, 70, 260);
        if (row.Cells["Closing Balance"].Value != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(row.Cells["Closing Balance"].Value.ToString(), font, brush, 70, 290);

        if (row.Cells["Status"].Value != null)
        {
            string cStatus = row.Cells["Status"].Value.ToString();
            if (cStatus == "Credit")
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString("جمع", font, brush, 40, 290);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString("بنام", font, brush, 40, 290);
            }
        }

        e.Graphics.DrawString("--------------------------------------------", linefont, brush, 20, 310);

        e.Graphics.DrawString("کسی بھی غلط حساب کی صورت میں جلد از جلد", infofont, brush, 19, 340);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("ہم سے رابطہ کریں۔ شکریہ", infofont, brush, 130, 365);

        e.Graphics.DrawString("03346565189 :فون نمبر" + " ", infofont, brush, 128, 395);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("آپ کے تعاون کا شکریہ", infofont, brush, 80, 425);


        currentRow++;
        e.HasMorePages = true;

        
    }
    else
    {
        currentRow = 0;
        e.HasMorePages=false;
    }

    
}
```

Despite my attempts to print each row on a separate page by setting e.HasMorePages to true after printing each row, the issue persists.

Comment: You need to debug your code, i.e. set a breakpoint and step through it line by line to see what it does that you don't expect or what it doesn't do that you do expect. If it does exactly what you expect and you still don't get the right results, it's your expectations that are wrong.

Comment: no it prints where i expect but the problem is that in my openion the new page does not change on time if any help in this i will be very gratefull

Comment: Does your PrintPage event handler get executed for times? Does the code process one page of data each time? Is it the correct page of data each time? I'm not asking about what you come out of the printer. I'm asking about what you see the code do in the debugger. If the code does all those things correctly then the issue is not the code. If the issue is the code then it will not do all those things correctly and you will be able to see that in the debugger.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. We should be able to copy and paste your code and see exactly what you're seeing. If we run the same code and see different behaviour then that indicates a system problem. If we do see the same behaviour then we can debug the code and find the issue. You can use the designer to build the form and then copy code from the designer code file too.

Comment: Learn how to use this site properly and then use it properly. No one wants your email address so I recommend you remove it before spammers scrape it from this page.